# Write a sentence In blade laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I want send description to page and if I don't send description use default from config file

in normal php I just write

```
<meta name="description" content="<?= if($replaceDescrption)?$replaceDescrption:$defaultDescrption">
```

how can I write this in laravel blade

```
<meta name="description" content="@if(yield('descrption'))?@yield('descrption'):{{config('app.description')}}">
```

I know I can send description with

```
@section('description',)
<meta name="description" content="replace des">
@endsection
```

put I need change in tow place

```
<meta property="og:description" content="@if(yield('descrption'))?@yield('descrption'):{{config('app.description')}}"/> 

<meta name="description" content="@if(yield('descrption'))?@yield('descrption'):config('app.description')">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@yield takes default value for 2nd argument:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="@yield('description', config('app.description'))"/>
```

Comment: beat me to it. So I'll toss a link to what I was gonna reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates